# Create Dictionary Iteratively using for loop in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python.I have created a small dictionary with the name Features.It has three keys in it.

```
print features.keys()
['Amy', 'LadyJesusFan777', 'rach']
```

I have written a small code below where get_count function returns a dictionary .I want three different dictionary with the name 'Amy' , 'LadyJesusFan777' , 'rach' mapped to the dictionary returned by the get_count function.But unfortunately my below code is returning only one dictionary with the name key.

```
for key in features.keys(): 
 key = get_count(features[key])
```

Code for get_count function.

```
def get_count(doc):

 pair1 = collections.Counter(doc)
 print pair1.keys()
 print pair1.values()

 return pair1
```

Please help me out.?

Comment: Show `features`, and where do you want to store those dictionaries? In other words, full input and full expected output.

Comment: In addition to what luk32 requested, what's the functionality of get_count? i.e. expected input and expected output?

Comment: @Sid  Get_count function outputs a dictionary.I want that dictionary to be named 'Amy'in first iteration,'LadyJesusFan777' in second iteration and so on i.e the name of keys of the feature dictionary.